# Unable to serve .terrain files in cesium sandcastle

Tags: javascript, terrain, cesium

I am learning 3d terrain generation using CesiumJS. I generated .terrain files usind [Cesium terrain builder](https://github.com/geo-data/cesium-terrain-builder) and kept them in 'cesium/apps' directory for testing purposes and to avoid CORS issues. Whenever, I try to generate terrain I get error that tile at X:0 Y:0 level 0 as well as tile at X:1 Y:0 level 0 were not found even though I added empty files at the specified locations.

Comment: Try https://assets.agi.com/stk-terrain/tilesets/world/tiles/1/0/0.terrain for a URL.

Answer (score 1):

Can you verify that the URL strings that the CesiumTerrainProvider is trying to access are accessible.  This is probably a simple path problem.